# Woocommerce - How to remove add to cart functionality and replace it with a link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to strip away the Add to Cart functionality where it brings you to the Cart and Checkout pages. I have already deleted these pages as I am setting up an affiliate site where products will instead link you to a place where you can buy them.

I have used some of the Woocommerce hooks to create functions that change the text of the button (it now says Check it Out), but is there a way to also change what happens when this button is pressed? Ultimately, I would want a product with a link specified on it. When they hit 'Check it Out' I just want a new window to open so the product can be viewed.

Is there a way to do this with hooks as well? Would it still be doing things in the background that would be interacting with the cart that need to be stripped out elsewhere?

Comment: product type as an external product will do this

Comment: Oh my god I had no Idea this existed. You had also answered my previous question around changing the button text but seems like no longer need to do this. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped